# libtxc-dxtn & libtxc-dxtn:i386 not found in ppa - 18.04 Bionic

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

I need `libtxc-dxtn` and `libtxc-dxtn:i386` for running SIMS 2 on Wine.

Adding the ppa and trying to install the packages with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libtxc-dxtn libtxc-dxtn:i386
```

Fails with the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libtxc-dxtn
E: Unable to locate package libtxc-dxtn:i386
```

My system:

```
$ uname -a
Linux dell2 4.15.0-20-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 24 06:16:15 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: I went to the PPA's Launchpad page and the info section states that the packages it provides are only for 16.04 and 16.10...also there's this warning: "*WARNING: Do not use this PPA with enabled HWE stack.*" If I'm not mistaken, 18.04's default kernel does have HWE stack enabled. Furthermore it says not to install packages individually: "This PPA is currently meant to be used as a whole. Please do _not_ individually install packages from it, add it to your sources and let your package manager pull in every update..."

Comment: See [PPA:xorg-edgers/ppa](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa). Lastly, you had the package name wrong (it's not `libtxc-dxtn:i386`), but it doesn't really matter since you're advised not to install packages individually

Comment: Frank, to get the output in English do a `set LANG=en_GB.UTF-8` and then execute the command if you don't want to translate...  (Bitte!  **;-)** )

Answer (score 4):

You can compile it from sources
Sources are not maintained since 2 years
The code is hosted on freedesktops git infrastructure at:
 http://cgit.freedesktop.org/~mareko/libtxc_dxtn/

Here is how to compile the `libtxc-dxtn` library
Run those lines as USER

```
# required stuff
sudo apt-get install mesa-common-dev
# get source files
cd ~/
wget https://people.freedesktop.org/~cbrill/libtxc_dxtn/libtxc_dxtn-1.0.1.tar.gz
tar xvfz libtxc_dxtn-1.0.1.tar.gz
cd libtxc_dxtn-1.0.1
# start the job
./configure
make
sudo make install
# clean up sources (optional)
cd ..
rm -rf libtxc_dxtn-1.0.1 libtxc_dxtn-1.0.1.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

The last supported release on that ppa for that package is `raring`, and the last release that they were included in Ubuntu was `artful`. That's only one version behind, so you could probably install those packages yourself:

```
wget https://lug.mtu.edu/ubuntu/pool/main/s/s2tc/libtxc-dxtn-s2tc_1.0+git20151227-2_i386.deb https://lug.mtu.edu/ubuntu/pool/main/s/s2tc/libtxc-dxtn-s2tc_1.0+git20151227-2_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./libtxc-dxtn-s2tc_1.0+git20151227-2_i386.deb ./libtxc-dxtn-s2tc_1.0+git20151227-2_amd64.deb
```

I got this information from https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/libtxc-dxtn-s2tc.

Note: the reason I suggest downloading from `lug.mtu.edu` instead of `archive.ubuntu.com` is `lug.mtu.edu` supports https, so you can be lazy and not bother to verify it with pgp ;).